# What is more efficient, bitwise or equality checking?

Tags: c#, performance, bit-manipulation

I was just writing a few conditional variables, and figured it would be easier to set a value to the result of the equality between 2 boolean values.

What would be faster/more efficient from a processing side, obviously this is marginal?

```
bool output = true&true;
```

or

```
bool output = true&&true;
```

I expect the latter as its a single equality check rather than computing the entire byte

---

Thanks and apologies on the vagueness previously. From Robbas answer, if the code is similar to:

```
bool input1 = GenerateFirstValue();
bool input2 = GenerateSecondValue();
bool output = input1 && input2;
```

A clear improvement is to Drop the first 2 lines into the declaration would mean when the value is false you would be more efficient over the bitwise checks, or presetting values. Especially when the logic has intensive methods.

```
    bool output = GenerateFirstValue() && GenerateSecondValue();
```

And even doing that, sort the checks by the least demanding first.

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: If **this** is the performance bottleneck in your application, *congratulations*. But also, if it is the bottleneck, it seems trivial to try both and measure it.

Comment: They will both be exactly the same at runtime, because they are constant expressions which the compiler will evaluate.  This is why the question can only be answered by you in the context of a real scenario.

Comment: @TimRogers: Absolutely. I wonder if the C# compiler is *required* to do that?

Comment: My code isn't directly using true:false, they are functions based on UI Controls. The idea of the question doesn't only apply to a simple boolean check, but could stack over multiple methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your hypothetical example I doubt very much that it matters as evaluating `true` is crazy fast (if not compiled away completely)

Take this example however:

```
bool output = veryLongFunction() & otherVeryLongFunction();
```

vs

```
bool output = veryLongFunction() && otherVeryLongFunction();
```

In this case the double && short circuits the expression if the first evaluates to false and is thus faster than using just one &.

Comment: My example was meant to be a simplified version. I didn't consider the equality not processing the 2nd check if the first fails. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in any doubt then profile it. But in your specific case these are both compile time evaluable constant expressions and the compiler will optimise them both out to the same result `bool output = true;`

In general though both arguments of `&` need to be evaluated, whereas for `&&` the second argument is only evaluated if the first one is `false`. For more complex expressions the difference can be significant.

You should also note that in general `a & b` *could* be `false` even if `a` and `b` separately evaluate to `true`. Consider `a = 0b01` and `b = 0b10` as an example.

Answer (score 0):

It *depends* on the *second* argument. Since `&&` construction

```
 bool output = left && right;
```

will be compiled into (pseudocode)

```
 if (left != 0)    // JZ or JNZ assembly instruction
   output = right
 else
   output = 0;
```

in case when `left` is `false`, `right` doesn't compute at all and if `right` is time consuming and `left` is `false` often enough then `&&` is a more efficient solution.

On the contrary, when both `left` and `right` are just `boolean` values, but *random ones* so the CPU branch predictor will be cofused and the condition

```
 if (left != 0)
```

often will be predicted *wrong*, it'll lead to `5-30` ticks *penalty*. As for `left & right`, it will be compiled into one `AND` or `MUL` assembly instruction (`1/3-1` tick).